# How to multiply in setValues in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, multiplication, setvalue

How do I multiply the value of quan (which is quantity) to price
I need to get the total of the price depending on the quantity that is ordered.
Thank you!!! :)

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            newForm.child("Food").setValue(food);
            newForm.child("Quantity").setValue(quan);
            newForm.child("Price").setValue(price);
            newForm.child("Table").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(FoodDetail.this, Menu.class));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to calculate total price.

```
newForm.child("Total_Price").setValue(quan*price);
```